# Typescript cannot find redux

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I am getting the following error:

```
node_modules/@types/react-redux/index.d.ts(8,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'redux'.
```

despite having installed both `react-redux` and `redux` (`package.json`):

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.42.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^15.0.18",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.42.9",
    "@types/react-redux": "^4.4.38",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2",
    "tslint": "^4.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1"
},
```

The `README.md` file in `@types/redux` says:

```
This is a stub types definition for Redux (https://github.com/reactjs/redux).
Redux provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/redux installed!
```

but uninstalling the `@types/redux` package makes no difference.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I thought that by adding an `index.d.ts` to the `@types/redux` directory (containing only `export * from ../../redux/index`), it would solve the problem, but no joy.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2015",
        "jsx": "react",
        "outDir": "build",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "__tests__",
        "index.android.js",
        "index.ios.js",
        "build",
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": false
}
```

and I definitely deleted the `@types/redux` directory from `node_modules`. I am (obviously) running TypeScript 2.2.1.

**UPDATE 2**

Code using `redux`:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux"

export default combineReducers({})
```

Note that adding a semicolon after `"redux"` does not help.

Comment: Yes, it should work without `@types/redux`. Actually, I think I had problems, when I had `@types/redux` installed... Could you provide a piece of code in which you're importing redux?

Comment: Just to be sure, put here your tsconfig.json as well.

Comment: `import { createStore, Store, Reducer } from 'redux'` this works just fine in typescript 2.3.0-dev.20170320

Comment: @Ralph make sure that `@types/redux` is really deleted from your `node_modules` directory and not just removed from your `package.json`

Comment: @Erik: Reverting to `@types/redux@3.6.31` fixed the problem. I suspect an issue with the TypeScript compiler.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I experienced the same problem on a react-native project. This fix worked for me:

You have to add "moduleResolution": "node" to the compiler options in order to include type definitions linked in package.json files.

Documentation here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: I'd guess you'd be forgiven for thinking that, when they say "Nowadays, this strategy is mainly present for backward compatibility." in their official docs, `classic` wouldn't be the default... This just solved me a whole lot of pain, thanks

Comment: That solved my issue as well. FTFM "There are two possible module resolution strategies: Node and Classic (...) If not specified, the default is Classic for --module AMD | System | ES2015 or Node otherwise." https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Answer (score 7):

I reverted to `@types/redux@3.6.31` and that resolved the problem. This version includes the `index.d.ts` file for redux. There might be a problem with the TypeScript compiler not looking for the `index.d.ts` file in the normal `node_modules/redux` directory, but only under `node_module/@types`.

Comment: forward 2022 this issue with that version is still presente but reverting to '@types/redux@3.6.31?' didn't fixed it

Answer (score 3):

If you encounter the same issue with the following react version `"^16.8.6"` verify if the npm redux package

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.13",
    "@types/node": "12.0.3",
    "@types/react": "16.8.19",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "typesafe-actions": "^4.4.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.1"
  },
```

if not installed just do `npm install redux` 
no need for `npm i @types/redux`as Redux package provides its own type definitions, so you don't need `@types/redux` installed!

Answer (score 2):

I already had `moduleResolution: 'node'` and `@types/redux` was deleted. But when I deleted `node_modules` and reinstalled, the problem went away. :shrug.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem.

Fixed with re-installing `redux` and save it.

`npm install redux --save`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after installing the redux toolkit. Interestingly, I did not have to re-install node modules. What worked for me is stopping and re-starting the live server -- problem gone!

1. on mac, on your VScode terminal, press "Control + C" to terminate the server
2. Run "npm start" again

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same issue,try following:

- Restarting vscode
- Deleting and reinstalling `node_modules`
- Restarting your PC(worked for me).